# Can't get system state change notifications if subscribed to HR/ECG

Tags: movesense

I'm working with Movesense 2.0.0 on a HR+ sensor, and I'm having this issue: if I subscribe (internally) to connector state changes it works as expected, but if I also subscribe to HR and/or ECG I stop getting connector state change notifications.
To reproduce it I just subscribed to HR in `hr_wakeup_app`
Is this behaviour expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current firmware the connector (stud) state goes to "unknown" (=2) when HR or ECG measurement is used. Upcoming release 2.1 will implement the "leads off" detection support which enables us to provide the connector state during ECG & HR measurement.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*